# Issues with poetry when deploying Django app to Render

Tags: django, render, python-poetry

I am following the “Getting Started With Django on Render” tutorial (https://render.com/docs/deploy-django#update-your-app-for-render) and all was going well until I got to “Configure Django for PostgreSQL”. I have everything copied correctly but I am getting errors now when I run python manage.py runserver this is the error:

```
File "/Users/user/Desktop/First_Program/Portfolio_Projects/Charter_Django_App/Charter_Django_App/config/settings.py", line 14, in <module>
    import dj_database_url
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_database_url'
```

even though when I run poetry show it clearly says it is installed

```
asgiref          3.5.2  ASGI specs, helper code, and adapters                                                                                                                                                                            
brotli           1.0.9  Python bindings for the Brotli compression library                                                                                                                                                               
dj-database-url  1.0.0  Use Database URLs in your Django Application.                                                                                                                                                                    
dj-email-url     1.0.6  Use an URL to configure email backend settings in your Django Application.                                                                                                                                       
django           3.2.16 A high-level Python Web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.                                                                                                                 
django-cache-url 3.4.2  Use Cache URLs in your Django application.                                                                                                                                                                       
environs         9.5.0  simplified environment variable parsing                                                                                                                                                                          
gunicorn         20.1.0 WSGI HTTP Server for UNIX                                                                                                                                                                                        
marshmallow      3.19.0 A lightweight library for converting complex datatypes to and from native Python datatypes.                                                                                                                      
packaging        22.0   Core utilities for Python packages                                                                                                                                                                               
psycopg2-binary  2.9.5  psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter                                                                                                                                                                    
python-dotenv    0.21.0 Read key-value pairs from a .env file and set them as environment variables                                                                                                                                      
pytz             2022.6 World timezone definitions, modern and historical                                                                                                                                                                
setuptools       65.6.3 Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages                                                                                                                                          
sqlparse         0.4.3  A non-validating SQL parser.                                                                                                                                                                                     
whitenoise       6.2.0  Radically simplified static file serving for WSGI applications
```

And also shows in poetry.lock file.
If anybody knows why this is happening and can please give me some insight. I followed the tutorial to the T but am new to using poetry.

I am also a bit confused as to where I store the environment variables such as SECRET_KEY as the tutorial is not very descriptive at that point. I am used to using `pip install environs[django]` then running
`env = Env() env.read_env()`
And reading from the .env file

Thank you x1000 in advance to anybody that may help me get my application running

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure as you didn't post that many things to begin with. But if you managed your virtual environment through poetry, then you should run :

```
poetry run python manage.py runserver
```

*(instead of `python manage.py runserver`)*

(As for environment variables, I've been advised to try [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv). I haven't had the chance to test it yet, but it seems easier than most things. I'm not sure if that will help you with render.yaml though...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I decided to use pipenv because that's what has been working for me and I also went with a different PaaS to deploy and everything is working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the **error** is from you're **virtualenv** either you're not **activating** it or the packages are not installed in the **virtualenv**.
if you are using vscode try `Ctrl + Shift + p` and **search** for `Python: select interpreter` make sure the **interpreter** vscode is using is you're venv if click on it and go to myvenv/Scripts/ there you can see a file python.exe choose it.